# how to convert a set of strings into a sets of characters, python?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk

l have a set of words (1000) words that l want to convert into a set of characters as follow :

```
words=['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

that l want to transform into :

```
characters_words=[['h', 'i'],['h', 'o', 'w'],['a', 'r', 'e'],['y','o','u']]
```

l tried :

```
x=list(words)
```

l got this error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: `characters_words = [list(x) for x in words]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be receiving that error unless you've overwritten `list` somewhere. Check and see if you've assigned `list` somewhere (`list=????`). Once you figure out what you did to `list`, this is what you want:

```
characters_words = [list(word) for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use comprehension like this:

```
words=['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']
print([list(x) for x in words])
# => [['h', 'i'], ['h', 'o', 'w'], ['a', 'r', 'e'], ['y', 'o', 'u']]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/narmdE)